Can I integrate Drupal document_ocr with tesseract?
I would like to use an open source image to text converter to populate text fields with in Drupal.
I tried setting the tesseract executable path in settings.php and thought that the document_ocr module would pick it up and add it to the processor selection.

I am looking to do the same thing. I tried the same thing too and it didn't get picked up as a possible processor.

The module supports Tesseract OCR starting with version 1.0.9
